# Is it possible to send an array in a POST, or assign multiple values in one input tag, and how?

Tags: php

I want to send *more than one value* in the POST but *use only one type of input tag*.

For example, is it possible to set the value of the **option tag** to both `$data['username_id]` and `$data['name']` and send it via the POST

```
<select name="owner" id="owner">
    <option value="NULL" selected="selected"></option>
    <?php
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users'
         . ' ORDER BY name';

    $query = mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die (mysqli_error($connect));

    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $data['user_id']; ?>"><?php echo $data['name']; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

I can't seem to retrieve on the other end. I have tried:

```
<option value="<?php echo $data['user_id','name']; ?>"><?php echo $data['name']; ?></option>
```

But still no luck.

Any help would be useful.

Comment: <select multiple> lets you select multiple options.

Comment: kainaw ,thank you very much for the quick reply.  I completely forgot about html elements and was trying  to solve  my problem with pure php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, is it possible to set the value of the option tag to both $data['username_id]' and $data['name'] and send it via the POST

Yes, this can be done, carefully.

**Working with your example:**

> ```
>  <option value="<?php echo $data['user_id','name']; ?>"><?php echo $data['name']; ?></option>
> ```

Can be simply rewritten as:

```
<option value='<?php echo $data['user_id']."--".$data['name']."'>"
               .$data['name']; ?></option>
```

At the other end:

On the form receiver PHP page:

```
$parts = explode("--",$_POST['owner']);
/***
 * $parts[0] = user_id
 * $parts[1] = name
 ***/
```

**BUT** as you are grabbing the data from a database row anyway, this is fairly pointless, you might as well *JUST* transport the user ID and simply use it on the receiving end to grab the `'name'` data value from the Database.

There is also *potential* issues if the splitter (`--`) appears more than once, so be carefully to choose a splitter that does not apper in either of the values you are trying to send.

---

**Working Freehand:**

```
 <input name="whatever[]" value="one">
 <input name="whatever[]" value="two">
```

The square bracket means that the data passed in `$_POST` will be an array of values.

As pointed out in [comments by Kainaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942968/is-it-possible-to-send-an-array-in-a-post-or-assign-mulitple-values-in-one-inp/43943077#comment74918457_43942968) you can also simply use the [`multiple` selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) to reach the same effect in your `<select>` input.

Comment: Upvoted for the **BUT**. If the name value is not editable, why bother sending it at all?

Comment: I am sending the name to an email function and a history function to have a readable history of where equipment has been

Comment: @Ir_123 on the same server?

Comment: Iam using a wamp server, so yes

Comment: @Ir_123 then that means  the page that makes the email can also connect to the MySQL and grab the data from the database. If you really want to send extra data that the user can't edit I would suggest you look at [Hidden form inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden).